# Identify all Media Manager images and videos based on metadata Field crieria

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, ecl, media-manager

We have request where we need to identify all Media Manager images and videos whose title is longer than 100 chars. The "title" is value of metadata field from metadata schema added on mm-stubschema. Also, plese note that this title is translated, so we need to check on all blueprint levels.
Ideally, we would like to do this via core service, but using ECl library with core service can be tricky.
The other option is to use TOM.NET to generate report, but this is wrong on so many levels, mostly because purpose of TOM.NET is not object manipulation.

Can someone propose the best solution and how we best tackle this issue.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think Coreservice is the best option for this. Did you try with core service ? Are you facing any issue with that ?

Comment: We haven't tried with core services, but, yes we also think its the best idea. We have never used ecl service, but i think there is always first time for everything. I saw that there is in documentation reference to service url: net.tcp://localhost:2660/ExternalContentLibrary/2012/netTcp We just need to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to this [blog post.](http://philipmedcraft.blogspot.com.br/2017/03/uploading-images-from-sdl-web-tridion.html)

The last section, "Updating the relationships in SDL Web (Tridion)", contains information on using the ECL service. This should help you.

Comment: HI Phil. Great blog. Thanks for sharing it. :D